# New Drupal Modules

Tags: 7

Not sure if this kind of questions are allowed to ask here.

Are there any sites which list drupal newly introduced modules, existing modules.

Going to drupal.org and searching for a module without knowing the modules name is taking time.

**EDIT**

I want to know if somebody introduced new module is there any site that list that new module name recently introduced.

so please tell me if there are any sites which list drupal newly introduced modules, existing modules.

Comment: Questions asking for links are not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [drupalmodules.com](http://drupalmodules.com/) is what you are after?

This page lists all new modules which has a stable release.
http://drupalmodules.com/new-modules

Answer (score 0):

please visit this website for the top and basic modules
http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/jays-top-50-drupal-7-modules

or

go to this link drupal.org/project/modules and use filter criteria "Sort by" and select "Date" it will show the recent added modules

Comment: Yeah your listed link is useful. But I want to know if somebody introduced new module is there any site that list that new module name recently introduced.

Comment: then go to this link http://drupal.org/project/modules and use filter criteria "Sort by" it will show the recent added modules